# Why does my Android Studio code randomly get underlined in red even when there is no error?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

Sometimes my code gets randomly underlined in red even when there is no error

[image: Image here]

For example, in my Kotlin code (screenshot above):

```
    nameTextView=findViewById(R.id.nameDashboardTextView)
    ageTextView=findViewById(R.id.ageDashboardTextView)
    emailIDTextView=findViewById(R.id.emailIDTextView)
    genderTextView=findViewById(R.id.genderTextView)
    weightTextView=findViewById(R.id.weightTextView)
    heightTextView=findViewById(R.id.heightTextView)
    progressBar3=findViewById(R.id.progressBar3)
```

findViewById of any random variables gets underlined in red. When I copy the text, remove it, and paste it back, the "error" is removed. Furthermore, the red line doesn't stop the code from compiling or executing, the application works perfectly, but in Android Studio, some random line like findViewById or other straightforward code will get underlined in red.

The error for the above example reads:

> Cannot infer type parameter T in
>
> fun  findViewById ( id:Int ) :T! None of the following
>   substitutions  (   Int)
>                                        (   Int)
>                                        (   Int) can be applied to
>                                        (   Int)

Any idea why this happens? I'm using Android Studio 3.1.3, 4th June 2018 build

Comment: Try to clean the project and compile it again.

Comment: might be caused by the IDE re-indexing your project, which happens from time to time

Comment: @GONZALOPANIAGUA, already did, the error still pops up randomly from time to time.

Comment: Well are you using any extension for findviewById? if not then you have to use `as TextView` here

https://medium.com/@quiro91/improving-findviewbyid-with-kotlin-4cf2f8f779bb

Comment: @Abk in that case it wouldn't be sporadic, but it will be happening constantly

Answer (score 0):

File->Invalidates caches...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).